# A particle is projected with velocity $v_0$ along $x$-axis. The deceleration on the particle is $a=\alpha x^2$

Tags: kinematics

The distance at the which the particle stops is

MY SOLUTION
$$a=v\frac{dv}{dx}$$
$$vdv=\alpha x^2 dx$$
Integrating 
$$\int_{v_0}^0 v\,dv=\int_0^x \alpha x^2\,dx$$
$$-\frac{(v_0)^2}{2}=\alpha \frac{x^3}{3}$$
$$x=(\frac{-3v_0^2}{2\alpha})^\frac13$$

The right answer is $[\frac{3v_0}{2\alpha}]^\frac13$. What’s going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer pointed out, the acceleration is $a=-\alpha x^2$. And using dimension analysis, we can see that the dimension of the "right answer" is not right, but yours is, because:
$$[x]=L$$
and
$$[v]=LT^{-1}$$
and
$$[a]=LT^{-2}$$
Which implies that
$$[\alpha]=T^{-2}L^{-1}$$
So
$$\left[\frac{v_0}{\alpha}\right]=L^{2}T$$
and
$$\left[\frac{v_0^2}{\alpha}\right]=L^{3}$$
In fact, we can calculate the only possible combination of $v_0$ and $\alpha$ to get length dimension: We want that
$$[v_0^n \alpha^m]=L$$
$$L^{n-m}T^{-n-2m}=L$$
Which means that $n-m=1$ and $-n-2m=0$, i.e. $n=2/3$ and $m=-1/3$. And the possible dimensionless combination is
$$[v_0^p \alpha^q]=1$$
$$L^{p-q}T^{-p-2q}=1$$
Which means that $p-q=0$ and $-p-2q=0$, i.e. $p=q=0$. So the solution must have the following form:
$$x=C v_0^{2/3} \alpha^{-1/3}$$
where $C$ is a dimensionless constant.

Comment: These questions always bother me, as there is no way for me to know if I am wrong or the answer is. I presume myself to be wrong, but even after investing a lot of time trying to solve it, I keep arriving at the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Deceleration is the opposite of acceleration, so you should write

$$ a = -\alpha x^2$$

Comment: That’s true, but it still won’t get me the final answer.

Comment: @Aditya Interesting.. I don't see any mistakes in the math. Where does your first equation come from?